# How many solutions are there for $a^b = 1$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I want to find out the solutions to the equation $a^b = 1$. I know the real solutions like $k^0 = 1, 1^k = 1, (-1)^{2k} = 1$. I want to know if I missed any real solutions for this. Also I know of complex solutions like $1,\omega, \omega^2, ......$.

The actual question which I wanted to solve using this is $(x^2 - 5x + 6) ^ {x^2 - 3x + 2} = 1$. I have the solutions that can be obtained by the above real solutions to $a^b = 1$. I want any other possible real or complex solutions for the second equation.

PS: My main concern is about the second equation only.

Edit 1: I have tried to solve this by the general forms of complex numbers. Like in

$\left(re^{i\theta}\right)^{\left(a+ib\right)}\ =\ 1$. This simplifies to: 
$\left(\frac{r^a}{e^{\theta b}}\right)\left(e^{\theta a}.r^b\right)^i\ =\ 1$

$( r.e^{(i*\theta)} ) ^ {(a+ib)} = 1.\;$ This simplifies to: $((r^a)/e^{(\theta . b)}) . (e^{(\theta . a)}*r^b)^i = 1.$

Edit 2: Are there any purely complex numbers ( in the form $(m + i*n)$ where $n \neq 0$ ) such that $k^i\ =\ 1$

Comment: Note that for $k^0=1$ you need to make sure that $k\ne 0$

Comment: What is your definition of $a^b$ ? In particular, what number spaces do $a$ and $b$ belong to ?

Comment: Hint: any complex number can be written as $z=Re^{i\theta},\mbox{where } R,\theta\in\Bbb R$

Comment: @g-fougeron Both a and b belong to the set of complex numbers.

Comment: So $b$ is not a positive integer?

Comment: b can be anything. By complex, I mean it can be of the form a+ib where b can be zero.

Comment: On how to write math: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I will note that for complex $a$ and $b$, $a^b$ is one well-defined number only when $a$ is nonnegative real or $b$ an integer. In the rest of the cases, $a^b$ have several values. For this note that $e^{(l+i(\theta+2\pi k))(x+iy)}$ depends on $k$, i.e. the exponent you pick in your polar representation.

Comment: @JosuéTonelli-Cueto Its Ok. Please just give a solution for x that satisfies the equation.

Comment: Full edition. Real and complex solutions.

Comment: Proved that there are infinitely many complex solutions.

Comment: @Holo what's wrong with $0^0:=1$ (by definition)?

Comment: @OskarLimka this definition is not Widely accepted, there are times where the convention is $0^0:=0$

Comment: @Holo, how so? I'm not aware of any use of $0^0=0$, but I'm curious if you have a reference.

Comment: You have the additional opportunity to mark any of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

$$\mathbf{\color{green}{Full\ edition.}}$$

$$\mathbf{\color{brown}{The\ issue\ equation,\ real\ roots.}}$$

Let us consider the equation
$$(y^2-y)^{y^2+y}=1,\quad \text{where } y=x-2.\tag1$$
The first special solution is $y_0=0,$ and the second is $y_1=-1.$
Then
$$y^2-y=1,\quad y_{3,4}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}2,$$ and there are all real roots.

$$\mathbf{\color{brown}{Equation\ a^a=1,\ complex\ roots.}}$$
This is a test example. The real roots are $0$ and $1.$

Let
$$a=re^{is},\tag2$$
then
\begin{align}
&a\log a = 2\pi mi,\\
&(r\cos s+ir\sin s)(\log r+is)=2\pi m i,\\
&\begin{cases}
r\cos s\cdot\log r - r\sin s\cdot s=0\\
r\sin s\cdot \log r + r\cos s\cdot s = 2\pi m,
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
&\begin{cases}
\log r = s\tan s\\
r s = 2\pi m \cos s,
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
&\begin{cases}
r\log r = 2\pi m\sin s\\
r s = 2\pi m \cos s,
\end{cases}\tag3
\end{align}
with [the numeric solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bs%3D%20asin(r%20log%20r%2F(2pi)),%20r%20s%20%3D%202%20pi%20cos%20s%7D)
$$\begin{pmatrix}m\\r\\s\end{pmatrix}=
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}1\\3.82059515\\0.95282627\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}2\\6.04151895\\1.04462732\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}3\\8.02197691\\1.08893606\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}4\\9.86707599\\1.11688251\end{pmatrix},\cdots
\right\}\tag4.$$

[Exact solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Ba,%20a%5Ea%7D,%20where%20a%3D%7Be%5Eproductlog(2i*pi*1),e%5Eproductlog(2i*pi*2),e%5Eproductlog(2i*pi*3),e%5Eproductlog(-2i*pi*4)%7D) $e^{W(2\pi m i)}$ are the same.

$$\mathbf{\color{brown}{Equation\ (y^2-y)^{y^2+y}=1,\ complex\ roots.}}$$

The complex roots can be found from the equation
$$(y^2+y)\mathrm{Ln}(y^2-y)=2\pi mi.\tag5$$
Let
$$y=u+iv,\tag6$$
then
\begin{align}
&y^2\pm y = u^2-v^2\pm u + i(2uv\pm v),\\[4pt]
&|y^2\pm y|^2 = |y|^2|y\pm1|^2 = (u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2\pm 2u+1),\\[4pt]
&\mathrm{Ln}(y^2-y)=\dfrac{2\pi mi}{|y^2+y|^2}(\Re(y^2+y)-i\Im(y^2+y)) = \dfrac{2\pi m}{|y^2+y|^2}(\Im(y^2+y)+i\Re(y^2+y))\\[4pt]
& = \dfrac{2\pi m(2uv+v)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)} + i\cdot \dfrac{2\pi m(u^2-v^2+u)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)},\\[4pt]
&u^2-v^2-u + i(2uv-v) = \exp\ \dfrac{2\pi m(2uv+v)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)}\\[4pt]
&\times\left(\cos\ \dfrac{2\pi m(u^2-v^2+u)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)}+i\sin\dfrac{2\pi m(u^2-v^2+u)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)}\right),
\end{align}
\begin{cases}
(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2-2u+1) = \exp\ \dfrac{4\pi m(2uv+v)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)}\\[4pt]
u^2-v^2-u = \exp\ \dfrac{2\pi m(2uv+v)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)}
\cos\ \dfrac{2\pi m(u^2-v^2+u)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)}\\[4pt]
2uv-v = \exp\ \dfrac{2\pi m(2uv+v)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)}
\sin\ \dfrac{2\pi m(u^2-v^2+u)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)}\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
or, taking in account the identity
$$\tan \dfrac t2=\dfrac{\sin t}{1+\cos t},\tag7$$
\begin{cases}
(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)\log((u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2-2u+1)) = 4\pi m(2uv+v)\\[4pt]
\tan\ \dfrac{\pi m(u^2-v^2+u)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)} 
= \dfrac{2uv-v}{\sqrt{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2-2u+1)} + u^2-v^2-u}.\tag8\\
\end{cases}
The system $(8)$ can be solved numerically.

$$\mathbf{\color{brown}{Equation\ (y^2-y)^{y^2+y}=1,\ solutions.}}$$

$\mathbf{\color{gray}{Case\ m=1.}}$

The system $(8)$ was solved, using MathCad, with the results
$$y=\{-1.9945685-0.9447719i,\ -0.1678984+1.4557984i,\ 1.7735670+0.6139028i\}.$$
The plot [of the first equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2)(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2%2B2u%2B1)log((u%5E2%2Bv%5E2)(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2-2u%2B1))%20%3D%201%204pi%20(2uv%2Bv)) and [of the second one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(sqrt((u%5E2%2Bv%5E2)(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2-2u%2B1))%2Bu%5E2-v%5E2-u)%20tan((1%20pi%20(u%5E2-v%5E2%2Bu))%2F((u%5E2%2Bv%5E2)(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2%2B2u%2B1)))%20%3D%20(2u-1)v) are

[image: m=1, First]
[image]

$\mathbf{\color{gray}{Case\ m=1.}}$

The system $(8)$ was solved, using MathCad, with the results
$$y=\{-2.4059865-1.2679361i,\ 0.0090403+1.9177304i,\ 2.0491421+1.0079400i\}.$$
The plots [of the first equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2)(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2%2B2u%2B1)log((u%5E2%2Bv%5E2)(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2-2u%2B1))%20%3D%202%204pi%20(2uv%2Bv)) and [of the second one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(sqrt((u%5E2%2Bv%5E2)(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2-2u%2B1))%2Bu%5E2-v%5E2-u)%20tan((2%20pi%20(u%5E2-v%5E2%2Bu))%2F((u%5E2%2Bv%5E2)(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2%2B2u%2B1)))%20%3D%20(2u-1)v) are

[image: m=2 First]
[image: m=2 Second]

Solutions [were verified using Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(y%5E2%2By)log(y%5E2-y)%3D4%20pi%20i), with the positive results.

$$\mathbf{\color{brown}{How\ many\ solutions?}}$$

Let us show that for any $m$ there are at least one solution.

Really, let 
$$F(u,v) = (u^2+v^2)\log(u^2+v^2)+(u^2+v^2)\log\left(u^2+v^2-2u+1\right) - \dfrac{4\pi m(2uv+v)}{u^2+v^2+2u+1},$$
then 
$$F\left(\dfrac12,\dfrac12\right)=\dfrac12\log\dfrac12+\dfrac12\log\dfrac14 -\dfrac{4\pi m}{\dfrac52}=-\dfrac32\log2-\dfrac85\pi m <0,$$
$$(u^2+v^2)\log\left(u^2+v^2-2u+1\right)>-\log2,$$
$$\dfrac{2uv+v}{u^2+v^2+2u+1}<1$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20%7B(2uv%2Bv)%2F(u%5E2%2Bv%5E2%2B2u%2B1)%7D,%20u%3E%3D0.5,%20v%3E%3D0.5))
$$(u^2+v^2)\log(u^2+v^2) -\log2-4\pi m \le F(u,v) \le 2(u^2+v^2)\log(u^2+v^2) -\dfrac85\pi m, $$
so there is a part of the the graph $F(u,w)=0$ [inside of the area](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7B(u%3E1%2F2)%20and%20(v%3E1%2F2)%20and%20(e%5E(productlog(4%2F5%20pi))%20%3C%20u%5E2%2Bv%5E2%3Ce%5E(productlog(4pi%2Blog2)))%7D) 
$$\left(e^{\frac12W(\frac45\pi m)}\right)^2 \le u^2+v^2 \le \left(e^{\frac12W(4\pi m+ \log2)}\right)^2,\quad u\ge\dfrac12,\quad v\ge\dfrac12,\tag9$$
where W(t) is Lambert W function (see also [Wolfram Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%7Be%5E(productlog(4pi%20m%2Blog%202)%2F2)%7D,%201%3Cm%3C15.)).

Similarly, let us consider the function
$$G(u,v)=\tan\ \dfrac{\pi m(u^2-v^2+u)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)} 
- \dfrac{(2u-1)v}{\sqrt{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2-2u+1)} + u^2-v^2-u}.$$
Using AM-GM for $u>\frac12$, one can get
$$\sqrt{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2-2u+1)}+u^2-v^2-u \le u^2+v^2-u+\dfrac12 = \dfrac14((2u-1)^2+1),$$
$$(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1) \le (u^2+v^2+u+\frac12)^2 = \dfrac14((u+\frac12)^2+\frac14+v^2),$$
or, taking in account inequality
$$\dfrac t{t^2+1}<\dfrac12,$$
$$G(u,v)\ge\tan\left(\pi ms(u,v)\right)- 2v,$$
where
$$s(u,v)=\dfrac{(u^2-v^2+u)}{(u^2+v^2)(u^2+v^2+2u+1)}.$$
If $m>2,$ then the line $2\pi ms(u,v)=\dfrac \pi2$ is inside the area $(9)$ 
(see also [Wolfram Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20((u-11.47)%5E2%2B(v-9.22)%5E2%3D0.04)%20and%20(v%3C%3Dsqrt(u%5E2%2Bu))%20and%20(sgn(u-0.5)%2Bsgn(v)%3E0)%20and%20(e%5E(productlog(200*4%2F5%20pi))%20%3C%20u%5E2%2Bv%5E2%3Ce%5E(productlog(200*4pi%2Blog2)))) for $m=200.$)

[image: The area of solution]

Easily to see that the solution is in the calculated area.

This shows that for each $m$ there are at least one solution.

Therefore, $\mathbf{\color{green}{there\ are\ infinitely\ many\ complex\  solutions\ of\ the\ equation}\\\color{brown}{(x^2-5x+6)^{x^2-3x+2} = 1.}}$

Answer (score 1):

Let's find all of complex solutions. Let $a=re^{i\theta}$ and $b=x+iy$therefore $$a^b=r^xe^{-\theta y}r^{iy}e^{i\theta x}=1$$ which leads to $$r^x=e^{\theta y}\\r^{iy}e^{i\theta x}=1$$which by simplification gives us$$x\ln r=\theta y\\y\ln r+ \theta x=2k\pi\qquad,\qquad k\in\Bbb Z$$we are looking for the solutions where $\theta=0,\pi$ and $y=0$. Substituting $y=0$ gives us$$x\ln r=0\\\theta x=2k\pi$$

If $r\ne 1$ then $\ln r\ne 0$ and **we have the trivial answer $x=0$ or $b=0$ and $a\ne 0$**.

If $r=1$ and $\theta=0$ the 2nd equality is satisfied with $k=0$ and **we have the trivial answer $a=1$ and any $b\in \Bbb R$**.

If $r=1$ and $\theta=\pi$ we have $$x=2k\quad,\quad\forall k$$which **gives us another trivial answer $a=-1$ and $b=2k$ where $k$ is integer**, therefore

> $$\\\LARGE\text{The trivial answers in real numbers are the only ones.}$$